# Why is there a brightness difference between usb-c/display port and HDMI on M1 Mac?

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, apple-silicon

I'm one of the lucky few (for now;) owning a brand new MacBook Pro M1 Pro. I've used a MBP 2017 till now and had it connected to my LG 38" display every day via usb-c.

Today I connected my new MBP to the same display via usb-c and the display looked dimmed and text kind of blurry, as if the brightness was at 30%. White was more like grey. I've looked through the settings of the monitor, as well as the macOS display settings and color profile - nothing seems to stand out. I also tried different options of text smoothing, as well as trying with a MacBook Air M1 - same problem there.

I decided to try the HDMI-port and connecting HDMI to the external display (actually using that for the first time) and everything was like I'm used to. White is white and text is crisp.

So, my problem is actually solved, but I would rather use usb-c as I then get access to the usb-hub built into the screen.

Anyone have any clue on why the usb-c ports behave different on the M1 Macs?

Comment: I have the opposite situation. My MBA 2020 (Intel) is usually connected to the external display via USB-C, and everything is ok. But sometimes I have to connect via HDMI adapter, and then the brightness looks dimmed. Have no idea, why.